# Facebook: Flash app, buttons don't work

Tags: flash, facebook, button

I have this app in Facebook:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/testcasemusic
```

The thing is, in Mac and some Windows nav (like Chrome or Firefox), the buttons in this app don't work. In this URL, you can see the correct functionality of this buttons:

```
http://iasa.me/test/presentacion.html
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am with Chrome and am using Win 7. The buttons behave the same in both the FB app and the standalone flash.